# SAS data manipulation for 2 table based on one column id

Tags: sas

I have 2 tables as followings:

Table 1

```
data table1;
   input id $ value;
   datalines;
   A 1
   A 2
   B 1
   B 2
   C 1
   D 1
   ;
```

Table 2

```
data table2;
   input id $ value;
   datalines;
   A 1
   B 2
   C 1
   D 1
   E 1
   ;
```

As you may observed that the unique id for table 1 is A, B, C, D.
I would like to delete observations those id in table2 do not appear in table1.

Therefore last observation of table2 should be deleted as E not in {A, B, C, D}

Desired output:

```
   A 1
   B 2
   C 1
   D 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `proc sql`:

```
proc sql;
    delete from table2
         where not exists (select 1 from table1 where table1.id = table2.id);
```

Comment: what if i wanna create a new table name Table2_1?

Comment: @useR . . . I don't understand your second comment.  In general, you should ask questions as questions and not in comments.